# How to create a vector column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

For example, I have a data frame:

`data <- data.frame(a=c(1,0,1),b=c(0,0,1),c=c(1,1,1),d=c(0,1,0))`

[image]

How can I add a vector column(not list) like this:

[image]

This 'combined' column is going to store the data of the entire row into a vector.

Comment: I think if you want to maintain the data as numeric, you are going to have to consider a list-column. Is there a reason you are trying to avoid this?

Comment: We already have several good and creative answers, but I strongly suspect this is a [xyproblem](https://xyproblem.info/). In downstream analyses, It is very unlikely that we may benefit from any method for storing the data.frame columns that does not include one of: vectors, tibbles(nested tibbles) or list columns, as variable classes.

The best answer we can give is probably just another question: why the need for this "nested vectors" solution?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the command to add such a column manually:

```
data = data.frame(a=c(1,0,1), b=c(0,0,1), c=c(1,1,1), d=c(0,1,0))

data$v = list(c(1,0,1,0), c(0,0,1,1), c(1,1,1,0))

data

#   a b c d          v
# 1 1 0 1 0 1, 0, 1, 0
# 2 0 0 1 1 0, 0, 1, 1
# 3 1 1 1 0 1, 1, 1, 0
```

Or within creation of the data frame:

```
data = data.frame(
  a = c(1, 0, 1),
  b = c(0, 0, 1),
  c = c(1, 1, 1),
  d = c(0, 1, 0),
  v = list(c(1,0,1,0), c(0,0,1,1), c(1,1,1,0))
```

UPDATE: I've read your question more carefully. Here is how to populate `data$v` from the rest of the data frame:

```
data = data.frame(a=c(1,0,1),b=c(0,0,1),c=c(1,1,1),d=c(0,1,0))
vtmp = vector('list', nrow(data))
for( i in 1:nrow(data) )
  vtmp[[i]] = as.vector(sapply(data, `[`, i));

data$v = vtmp;

data

#   a b c d          v
# 1 1 0 1 0 1, 0, 1, 0
# 2 0 0 1 1 0, 0, 1, 1
# 3 1 1 1 0 1, 1, 1, 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit, using `split()` to make a list of dataframes:

```
data$combined <- split(data, 1:NROW(data))
```

You say "not a list", we can use paste to make a string:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- mutate(data, combined = paste(a,b,c,d))

#   a b c d combined
# 1 1 0 1 0  1 0 1 0
# 2 0 0 1 1  0 0 1 1
# 3 1 1 1 0  1 1 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

An option in `base`:

```
data <- data.frame(a=c(1,0,1),b=c(0,0,1),c=c(1,1,1),d=c(0,1,0))
data$combined <- as.array(
  sapply(X = seq(nrow(data)), 
         FUN = \(i) unname(unlist(data[i, ])), 
         simplify = FALSE))
```

gives

```
> class(data$combined) # not a list 
[1] "array"
> data
  a b c d   combined
1 1 0 1 0 1, 0, 1, 0
2 0 0 1 1 0, 0, 1, 1
3 1 1 1 0 1, 1, 1, 0
```

Comment: Nicely done. I didn't make it a one-liner

Answer (score 1):

```r
data$combined <- apply(data, 1, toString)
```

Note: `data$combined` is character.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `as.matrix` + `asplit`

```
data$combined <- asplit(as.matrix(data), 1)
```

and you will obtain

```
> data
  a b c d   combined
1 1 0 1 0 1, 0, 1, 0
2 0 0 1 1 0, 0, 1, 1
3 1 1 1 0 1, 1, 1, 0
```

Comment: I recently noted: If matrix tricks are an option, look at Thomas's answers (+1).